# Mathematics functions by string, JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string, math

I'm looking for a function that return me a mathematic function following those examples:

```
The_Function_I_Need("x^2") = function(x) { return math.pow(x, 2) }
The_Function_I_Need("x*2+5") = function(x) { return 2*x+5 }
The_Function_I_Need("x+y") = function(x, y) { return x+y }
```

And more..

Answer (score 1):

```js
var The_Function_I_Need = {
  "x^2": function(x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
  },
  "x*2+5": function(x) {
    return 2 * x + 5;
  },
  "x+y": function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}

console.log(The_Function_I_Need["x^2"](4))
console.log(The_Function_I_Need["x*2+5"](4))
console.log(The_Function_I_Need["x+y"](2, 4))
```

Comment: I guess that's one way to do it.  Just hard-code the formulas instead of trying to make a parser.

Comment: Call me Mr. Pragmatic ;)

Answer (score -1):

The Javascript `eval()` function can evaluate a string as an expression.
To follow your example, you could just use `eval("x^2")`.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: Except for the fact that `x^2` doesn't evaluate to "x-squared".  The `^` operator is [Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR).

Comment: Good catch.  I focused on the essence of the question and missed that, thanks!